# Gson парсер

Tags: java, парсер

Привет всем.
Имеется строка

```
[{
"name":"TEXT",  
"author": {
    "name": "ololo" 
  }
},

{
"name":"TEXT2",  
"author": {
    "name": "ololo" 
  }
}]
```

Чтобы извлечь `name` проблем не возникает.
Использую следующий код:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Parse[] parse = gson.fromJson(str, Parse[].class);

for (int i = 0; i < parse.length; i++)
{
      String name = parse[i].getName().toString();
}
```

Но как мне получить `name` у `author`?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Parse {
    private String name;
    private Author author;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Author getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
}

public class Author {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: то, что надо.
спасибо!

Comment: @odradek если ответ верный, отметьте его как принятый и если все совсем хорошо, не забудьте поднять репутацию @falstaf